# Cpanel Number of processes exceeds and Django App crashes

Tags: django, optimization, redis, celery, cpanel

I am very new to deploying Python (Django=4.1) applications on Cpanel(Shared). I have successfully hosted one app with celery, redis, etc. The issue is, every time I start using the app, the total number of processes(Cpanel) exceeds(120/120) and the app stops working. I have been trying to learn about the number of processes and how to optimize the application. Yet no success. Can somebody describe the following?

1. What is the number of processes at Cpanel?
2. How is my app related to this?
3. How can I optimize my application?
4. How to keep the application working?
   This Python(Django, DRF, Celery, Redis, Requests) app is supposed to be used by 5,000 users.

I tried to learn about 'number of processes and entry processes' online. No luck. Went through a few articles to learn how to optimize Django app.